# CTE incorrect syntax near ")"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to use a sql query that has the following structure:

```
WITH 
table1 
    AS (QUERY1)
, table2 
    AS (QUERY2)
, myCTE (COLUMNS OF THE CTE)
    AS (CTE_QUERY)  
    SELECT * FROM myCTE),
 ,anotherCTE...
```

I'm getting an "Incorrect syntax error near ')' near "myCTE)".

Comment: Show your actual code or a reasonable shortening of it that has the same problem.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Why do you want another CTE after you selection?

Comment: Actually the entire query is built by assembling subqueries in a C# code, that's why i have many CTEs, the queries were written in Oracle using CONNECT BY so I transformed them into CTEs... @HoneyBadger

Comment: All ctes have to follow each other. You can only do a select after all ctes are defined. If you want to fire more selects better use temp tables instead of ctes. If you explain *what* you are trying to do (as opposed to *how*), we may be able to help you better.

Comment: I think you have a sintax error... near ')'

Comment: Actually the previous code used the Oracle SELECT CONNECT BY PRIOR syntax, and the result of such queries was then used with aliases via the WITH clause, that's what I want to do with the SQL Server CTE Syntax, the myCTE alias must be used in further queries to refer to the data corrsponding to the previous CONNECT BY in Oracle syntax @HoneyBadger

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty clear.  You have an extra `)`:

```
myCTE)
```

should be

```
myCTE
```

Comment: ...And an extra comma, and what's with the `anotherCTE` after the selection. Will never work...

Comment: This corrects the error but I get another error message in the next comma ', anotherCTE' , I get the message "Incorrect syntax near ','".* @HoneyBadger

Answer (score 1):

As you already found out, the extra ) shouldn't be there:

```
WITH 
table1 
    AS (QUERY1)
, table2 
    AS (QUERY2)
, myCTE (COLUMNS OF THE CTE)
    AS (CTE_QUERY)  
    SELECT * FROM myCTE
```

The second error you reported is because you are attempting to do another CTE after selecting from the above CTE. You aren't allowed to do that, but end the CTE with a `SELECT` statement.

If you somehow need AnotherCTE for anything, you could resolve that by declaring it prior to the `SELECT` you already did, like so:

```
WITH 
table1 
    AS (QUERY1)
, table2 
    AS (QUERY2)
, myCTE (COLUMNS OF THE CTE)
    AS (CTE_QUERY)  
 ,anotherCTE...
SELECT * FROM myCTE
```

However, that would imply you don't really need anotherCTE to begin with. If you do need it, simply move down the `SELECT` statement to be the final statement in your query.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add a `;` before `WITH`statement

Comment: No you don't **have** to.

Comment: The WITH statement has to be the first statement in the batch, thus the ";". It's not required if there's nothing happening before it.

Answer (score 0):

there is an extra ")" on SELECT * FROM myCTE

```
 WITH 
    table1 
        AS (QUERY1)
    , table2 
        AS (QUERY2)
    , myCTE (COLUMNS OF THE CTE)
        AS (CTE_QUERY)  
        SELECT * FROM myCTE),
     ,anotherCTE...
```